# How to implement dummy values in Grails g:selects?

Tags: html, grails, select, gsp

In pure HTML, I might have a `<select>` that looks something like this:

```
<select id="colors">
    <option id="0" selected="selected" value="choose">Choose a color</option>
    <option id="1" value="red">Red</option>
    <option id="2" value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option id="3" value="green">Green</option>
</select>
```

Hence the first `<option>` is just a "dummy" value; that is, its just filler text that explains to the user that they must select a color. I might even throw some styling on it so that it appears grayed-out/disabled so that users know it is not a viable selection.

But in Grails, we inject the model *into* the select:

```
// Inside ColorsController
def index() {
    // Returns a list of 3 colors for: R, G, B
    List<String> colors = getRedGreenAdnBlue()

    render(view: "colors", model: colors)
}

// Inside colors.gsp
<g:select name="colors" from="${colors}" />
```

But then this only produces:

```
<select id="colors">
    <option id="1" value="red">Red</option>
    <option id="2" value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option id="3" value="green">Green</option>
</select>
```

See how I've now lost my "*Choose a color*" dummy value? I *know* I could do some jQuery on page load to insert this value at the top of the option list, but I'm wondering if this is a usage pattern that Grails already comes equipped to handle. So I ask: **Is there a Grails way of solving this problem?**

Comment: What about using noSelection attribute of the g:select tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use noSelection:

```
<g:select name="colors" from="${colors}" noSelection="['':'Choose a color']"/>
```

Here is the docs: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/select.html